# ObserveEvent removes addCircleMarkers group when clusterOptions argument is present -- expected behavior?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a Shiny application that renders a leaflet map. On this map I use addCircleMarkers to add two different groups containing location markers (one group is called "locations" and another group is called "customers"). I am using observeEvent to allow the user to click on a "locations" marker and then have all "customers" markers become visible that are associated with that particular "location". Clicking on different location markers will show different customers.

I was able to get all this working, and in my code, I have a condition that checks whether a marker from the "locations" group has been clicked, or whether a marker from the "customers" group has been clicked (customers are cleared and redrawn whenever a new location is clicked). However, after incorporating the clusterOptions argument in addCircleMarkers, clicking on a marker would crash the app. After adding a print to console on marker click, I noticed that the "group" argument only appears when clusterOptions is not listed as an argument.

Below is a simplified version of my code that renders a leaflet with with 3 map points. When you click on a marker, the print() outputs the group "locations" from the clicked marker to the R console.

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

# Create 3 map points -- 2 will be clustered

map_points <- bind_rows(c(location = 'A', lon = -122.4, lat = 37.8),
                        c(location = 'B', lon = -122.4, lat = 37.8),
                        c(location = 'C', lon = -118.2, lat = 34.0))

map_points$lon <- as.numeric(map_points$lon)
map_points$lat <- as.numeric(map_points$lat)


# Shiny

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(map_points) %>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~lon, 
                        lat = ~lat, 
                        group = "locations", 
                        layerId = ~location
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$mymap_marker_click, {
    print(input$mymap_marker_click)
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Screenshot of print to console after clicking marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5zQK.jpg)

However, if I take the same code and add a clusterOptions argument to addCircleMarkers, the group disappears.  $clusterId is added from the new argument, but I don't see a reason why $group would no longer be there.

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

# Create 3 map points -- 2 will be clustered

map_points <- bind_rows(c(location = 'A', lon = -122.4, lat = 37.8),
                        c(location = 'B', lon = -122.4, lat = 37.8),
                        c(location = 'C', lon = -118.2, lat = 34.0))

map_points$lon <- as.numeric(map_points$lon)
map_points$lat <- as.numeric(map_points$lat)


# Shiny

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(map_points) %>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~lon, 
                        lat = ~lat, 
                        group = "locations", 
                        layerId = ~location,
                       # adding clusterOptions removes the group in observeEvent
                        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions() 
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$mymap_marker_click, {
    print(input$mymap_marker_click)
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Screenshot of print to console after clicking marker - with clusterOptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5atEe.jpg)

Is there a way I can use the clusterOptions argument without having the group disappear?